# If a matrix field is set to "Only save blocks to the site they were created in", do the translation options for the sub-fields do anything?

Tags: localization

Sanity check...
If a matrix field is set to "Only save blocks to the site they were created in", do the translation options for the sub-fields in the blocks of that matrix field actually do anything? The blocks won't be saved into other sites, therefore do the translation options for those blocks > subfields do nothing?

Matrix settings:

[image: Matrix settings:]

Field settings for the block inside the matrix:

[image: Field settings for the block inside the matrix:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. If you disable propagation, the blocks will only be saved for the site they are created in. So translations will never be visible anywhere. In order not to confuse users, I'd set all the nested fields to *Not translatable* as well.

**In theory**, you could access blocks from different sites with a different language in your frontend templates, in which case the translations for the nested fields *might* become relevant. But you'd have to be pretty creative to come up with a use-case for that …

Comment: Perfect, thank you!